# Change color block based on string % with array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop

I have values: `1,5,7,2,25,2,6` and I would like to give all values a specific % which will be related to color.

So the highest value is `25` -100%.
The lowest value is `1` - 10%.

This is a preview look with many values:
[image]

Having these numbers I would like to check other numbers %, but I want to do same thing with 10 other colors:

```
.100 {
  color: rgb(30, 144, 255);
}
.90 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.9);
}
.80 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.8);
}
.70 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.7);
}
.60 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.6);
}
.50 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.5);
}
.40 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.4);
}
.30 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.3);
}
.20 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.2);
}
.10 {
  color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.1);
}
```

I tried so far:

```
$a_c_a = '1,5,7,2,25,2,6';

$a_c_a_min = min(array_filter($a_c_s));
$a_c_a_max = max(array_filter($a_c_s));

$a_c_a_min_10 = $a_c_a_min;
$a_c_a_max_100 = $a_c_a_max;

if (1 == $a_c_a_max) {
  $class_2 = '.100';
} elseif (1 == $a_c_a_min) {
  $class_2 = '.10';
}

if (5 == $a_c_a_max) {
  $class_3 = '.100';
} elseif (5 == $a_c_a_min) {
  $class_3 = '.10';
}

if (7 == $a_c_a_max) {
  $class_4 = '.100';
} elseif (7 == $a_c_a_min) {
  $class_4 = '.10';
}

[...] up to number 6
```

**Output should be:**

```
 $class_1 = '.50'; (1)
 $class_2 = '.70'; (5)
 $class_3 = '.90'; (7)
 $class_4 = '.60'; (2)
 $class_5 = '.100'; (25)
 $class_6 = '.60'; (2)
 $class_7 = '.80'; (6)
```

Note: Also If values will be `1,2,1,1,3` then I would like to use `.100` and `.90` and `.80` - from highest.

Comment: `$a_c_s` is a string, not an array, you need to use `explode()` to turn it into an array.

Comment: Sure, I just shortened the code `$a_c_a = '1,5,7,2,25,2,6';` AND `$a_c_s = explode(',', $a_c_a);`.

Answer (score 1):

First use `array_unique()` to get all the different values of the array, and `sort()` to order them. Then you can create an associative array to map these sorted values to the corresponding percentages.

```
$percentages = array(100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10);
$unique_values = array_map('intval', array_unique($a_c_s));
rsort($unique_values);
$percent_map = array_combine($unique_values, array_slice($percentages, 0, count($unique_values)));

foreach ($a_c_a as $val) {
    echo $val . " - " . $percent_map[$val] . "%<br>";
}
```

Comment: @HubertFurka You're calling `explode()` on an array. That's messing everything else up.

Comment: @HubertFurka Any time you have variables with numbered names like that you're doing something wrong. You should be using an array.